# Dynamic filter system only filtering the "text"

Tags: excel, vba, filter, listbox

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to create a VBA ListBox filtering macro. I found an example and I transferred my data to the lists. VBA dynamic filter system is only filtering the "text", how can I filter "text and numeric" ?

Is this about textbox1 ?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim ls, rs As Worksheet
Set ls = Sheets("Liste")
Set rs = Sheets("Rapor")
x1 = ls.Range("1:1").End(xlToRight).Column
y1 = ls.Range("a250000").End(xlUp).Row
x2 = rs.Range("1:1").End(xlToRight).Column
y2 = rs.Range("a250000").End(xlUp).Row
rs.Range(rs.Cells(1, 1), rs.Cells(y2, x2)).Clear
rs.Range("Z1") = ComboBox1
rs.Range("Z2") = "*" & TextBox1 & "*"
Sheets("liste").Range(ls.Cells(1, 1), ls.Cells(y1, x1)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=rs.Range("Z1:Z2"), CopyToRange:=rs.Range("A1"), Unique:=False
x2 = rs.Range("1:1").End(xlToRight).Column
y2 = rs.Range("a250000").End(xlUp).Row

ListBox1.ColumnCount = x2
i = rs.Range(rs.Cells(1, 1), rs.Cells(y2, x2))
ListBox1.List = i
End Sub
```

Comment: Some small examples of the type of data you want to filter and what results you expect would help here

Comment: Also - if this doesn't work when using AdvancedFilter manually, it won't work using VBA to automate the process.